# Fatal error in Autoloader.php on line 34 phpExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, autoloader

I want to use phpExcel, but when run the script I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Exception' with message 'Multibyte function overloading in PHP must be disabled for string functions (2).' in D:\Apache\htdocs\phpExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Autoloader.php:34 Stack trace: #0 D:\Apache\htdocs\phpExcel\Classes\PHPExcel.php(32): require() #1 D:\Apache\htdocs\phpExcel\index.php(19): include('D:\Apache\htdoc...') #2 {main} thrown in D:\Apache\htdocs\phpExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Autoloader.php on line 34
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Option 1**: If you have access to your **php.ini** file, set this `mbstring.func_overload = 0`

It's a requirement of PHPExcel, in their **Autoloader.php** file:

```
...
if (ini_get('mbstring.func_overload') & 2) {
    throw new PHPExcel_Exception('Multibyte function overloading in PHP must be disabled for string functions (2).');
}
...
```

**Option 2**: If you don't have privileges to edit **php.ini**, you can setup this in an **.htaccess** file:

```
php_value mbstring.func_overload 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I edited `mbstring.func_overload = 2` to `mbstring.func_overload = 0`

Comment: What people will do if someday SO shutdown, Thanks a lot, it's still up and running 24x7.