# How to disable Multibyte function overloading in PHP for string functions

Tags: php, phpexcel, autoloader, mbstring

I got a problem when call the PHPExcel library AutoLoader.php file.

I try to upload the Excel file, then after clicking on the upload button, it saves data into the database. I get an error, as shown in the photo after uploading the file. How can I fix this?

[image]

```
<?php

require('library/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');

/** Include path **/
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../Classes/');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if((isset($_POST['file'])) && !empty($_POST['file']))
    {
        $file = $_POST['file'];
    }

    $fileName= $_FILES["file"]["name"]; 
    echo ('fileName +'.$fileName);
    //$uploadPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/SMS/excel/' ;

    $fileTempName= $_FILES["name"]["temp_name"];    
    //echo ('fileTempName +'.$fileTempName);    
    $fileExtension= pathinfo($fileName,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);     
    $allowedtype= array('xlsx','sls','xlsm');

    if(!in_array($fileExtension,$allowedtype)){

        echo("<br/>Sorry, File type is not allowed. Only Excel file.");     
    }

    else { 
        echo("Correct File Extension");         

            try
            {
                $inputfiletype = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($fileName);
                $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputfiletype);
                $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);

                echo 'Reading the number of Worksheets in the WorkBook<br />';
                /**  Use the PHPExcel object's getSheetCount() method to get a count of the number of WorkSheets in the WorkBook  */
                    $sheetCount = $objPHPExcel->getSheetCount();
                echo 'There ',(($sheetCount == 1) ? 'is' : 'are'),' ',$sheetCount,' WorkSheet',(($sheetCount == 1) ? '' : 's'),' in the WorkBook<br /><br />';

                echo 'Reading the names of Worksheets in the WorkBook<br />';
                /**  Use the PHPExcel object's getSheetNames() method to get an array listing the names/titles of the WorkSheets in the WorkBook  */
                    $sheetNames = $objPHPExcel->getSheetNames();
                foreach($sheetNames as $sheetIndex => $sheetName) {
                    echo 'WorkSheet #',$sheetIndex,' is named "',$sheetName,'"<br />';
                }

            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($fileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
            } 

        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650886/fatal-error-in-autoloader-php-on-line-34-phpexcel)

Comment: @Wizard I alrdy tried but didn't work .

Comment: If you tried by eiting the php.ini file, did you edit the correct file, did you restart your webserver afterwards?